# How to create .txt from a Gdocs Using Google App maker?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I'm trying to create a `.txt` file from a Gdocs using Appmaker the only problem is the `getAs('application/csv')` or `getAs(MimeType.CSV)` is not supported in AppMaker.

Does anyone have any idea how to do it differently?

```js
var blob = Doc.getAs(MimeType.CSV);
```

Comment: Please provide details in regards to where you are using this script, server or client? Also, is this a Google Doc or Google Sheet? Also might help to post more than just one line of code as your problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your comment , fisrt ,it is written that it is a Gdocs , second, it has nothing to do with if it a client or a server side scripting , the question was clear that I'm looking for an equivalent for getAs(MimeType.CSV) because it is not supported by AppMaker .

Comment: So the reason I asked for clarification if it was a doc or sheet is because you are wanting a csv version of it which is more common for to use for a sheet, whereas a txt version is more common for a document. Also in regards to the client/server question, I have seen many cases where people tried using scripting reserved for the server side in the client side, so I just wanted to make sure your script was located in the correct category. As far as the get as function goes you are correct it does not appear to be supported, but it is Google Apps Script not App Maker. Proposed solution below.

Answer (score 2):

**Make a text file**

**Script:**

```
function makeATextFile() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var s='';
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    r.forEach(function(c,j){
      if(j>0)s+=',';
      s+=Utilities.formatString('%s',vA[i][j] );
    })
    s+='\n';
  })
  var folderId=DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents().next().getId();
  var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMddyyyyHHmm")
  DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(ts+'.txt', s);
}
```

**Data Sheet:**

[image]

**Text File**

[image]

> Google Apps Script runs in App Maker.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly appears the getas() function is not supported, however it's not a specific problem to App Maker but rather has to do with Google Apps Script which is used to run server scripts in AM.

The following is a proposed workaround and may not fit your exact needs but some testing resulted in promising results:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);
var name = doc.getName();
var text = doc.getBody().getText();

DriveApp.createFile(name, text, MimeType.CSV);
```